# Getting 502 bad gateway when deploying Azure bot to azure

Tags: azure, botframework, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to publish a basic echo bot to azure but I'm getting a 502 bad gateway while deploying. 
If I run the bot locally it works fine.

The bot code is the following, from the devoloper community. It's a sample echo bot to connect to alexa:

https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/samples/Alexa%20Adapter%20Sample

The error I get is the following:

[image]

This is what I get while using the bot emulator:

[image]

While this is the error I get on the web chat channel: 
[image]

Comment: can you post your deployment steps? Also, the error on the Emulator is due to ngrok, you will need to configure ngrok to make it work as expected. Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/406 and https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/945

Answer (score -2):

It seems you don't have ngrok installed and configured.You need it to allow the emulator to accept remote calls from the remote bot in azure

Check these: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/Tunneling-(ngrok)
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think this is the problem because if I use the web app bot on the portal I can't connect to the bot either.